# R, plot keeps appearing in bottom left corner instead of centered

Tags: r

For some reason, when using ordihull and orditop to create a plot for my NMDS plot, I cannot for the life of me get it to be centered. I am using RStudio.

I have tried to reset the plot area using `dev.off()`, followed by `plot.new()` and using default values such as `par(mfrow=c(1,1) par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))`.

But here is an image of what my plot looks like using `plot.new(), par(mar=c(10,10,10,10))`

[image]

No matter what I put in `par(mar)`, it is always cutting off my plot. I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: Once I had similar issue and solved it by using ggplot2. Here is an example how to do it with ggplot2: `https://chrischizinski.github.io/rstats/vegan-ggplot2/`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when using ggplot2 (which is one the libraries I did load), the plot works by first running an empty plot such as `plot(example_NMDS)` without any other features, or running `plot(example_NMDS, type="n")` to set up the empty space first. Then run ordiplot. I think `ordiplot(type="none")` will also do the trick.